# Any way to reduce suite setup/teardown and test setup/teardown boilerplate in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am working on a project that is getting fairly large and complicated.

In our Robot test files, we now have several suite setup/teardown and test setup/teardown that handles spawning mock servers for third party services, resetting configuration, overriding the generation of random values so our test output stays predictable, etc.

Because of all the setup/teardown that is required for each test file, the amount of boilerplate in the settings section is getting pretty silly.

**What would be the "canonical" way to reduce this test setup boilerplate?** I can't simply gather all the setup/teardown statements into a couple of keywords and use those instead, as the test suites don't all have the exact same requirements.

For example, is there any way in the Robot Framework for a test library (specifically Python) to add setup/teardown actions? That way I could just set some metadata in the settings section and have the test library add setup/teardown actions as needed.

For example, I could add a metadata header like `Metadata   Uses services   Twitter, Facebook`, then the test library would handle the suite-level setup/teardown for spawning and killing the mock servers and the test-level setup/teardown for cleaning up their state.

Answer (score 5):

You could play with [library scopes](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-scope). For example with `SUITE` scope there will be a new instance created for every suite.

> A new instance is created for every test suite. The lowest-level test suites, created from test case files and containing test cases, have instances of their own, and higher-level suites all get their own instances for their possible setups and teardowns.

This gives you control when the constructors and destructors will be invoked. Then these, so the [constructors of the libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#providing-arguments-to-libraries) and the destructors could act like "setups" and "teardowns". You could even move the metadata setting into the constructor.

Here is an example using `TEST` scope:

```py
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class lib(object):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST'
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 0.1

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.test_name = 'setup'
        BuiltIn().set_suite_metadata('META', 'value', append=True)
        BuiltIn().log_to_console(f'\n                 init {x}')

    def kw(self, test_name):
        self.test_name = test_name
        BuiltIn().log_to_console(f'                 keyword {self.test_name} - {self.x}')
        
    def __del__(self):
        BuiltIn().log_to_console(f'                 del {self.test_name}')


globals()[__name__] = lib
```

test.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    lib    111

*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    kw   ${TESTNAME}
    
Test 2
    kw   ${TESTNAME}
    
Test 3
    kw   ${TESTNAME}
```

Output:

```
Bence:[Robotframework/SO_material]# robot --pythonpath . test.robot

                 init 111
                 del setup
==============================================================================
Test
==============================================================================
Test 1
                 init 111
                 keyword Test 1 - 111
Test 1                                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 del Test 1
Test 2
                 init 111
                 keyword Test 2 - 111
Test 2                                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 del Test 2
Test 3
                 init 111
                 keyword Test 3 - 111
Test 3                                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 del Test 3
Test                                                                  | PASS |
3 critical tests, 3 passed, 0 failed
3 tests total, 3 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```